# Planarity of a 3D curve defined parametrically

Tags: geometry, 3d

If you have a 3D curve defined parametrically by $t$ for example:

$$P=\cos\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \frac{3}{2} {\bf i} + 3 \sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) {\bf j} + \cos\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \frac{3\sqrt3}{2} {\bf k}$$

How do you determine if it lies in a certain plane?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You can use "{\bf a}" to get **a** in equations.

Comment: A plane can be defined by a planes equation for example. If that is the case then just insert the coordinates into the plane and see which $t$ it's true for.

Comment: That is not a point, but a curve in 3D.

Comment: @mathreadler or `\mathbf{a}`

Comment: I have changed your title to put it in conformity with the words that are usual in this context, and are likely to be used for queries. Do you agree with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general answer is that a necessary and sufficient condition for a curve to be planar is that its torsion, given by the following formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve)

$$\tau=\dfrac{\det(P'(t),P''(t),P''(t))}{\|P'(t) \times P'''(t)\|}$$

**is zero.** (under the condition that the third derivative exists...), itself reducible to the simpler criterion:

> > $$\tag{1} \det(P'(t),P''(t),P'''(t))=0.$$

For the example you give, we easily check that condition (1) is fulfilled. In fact, setting $T=t-\pi/4$ and factorizing the coefficients, we obtain:

$$\left|\begin{array}{rrr}-\sin(T)&-\cos(T)&\sin(T)\\ 
\cos(T)&-\sin(T)&-\cos(T)\\
-\sin(T)&-\cos(T)&\sin(T)\end{array}\right|$$

which is $0$ because rows 1 and 3 are identical.

But in this case, there is a simpler way.

It suffices to obseerve the following **implication**

$$\begin{cases}
x= \frac{3}{2}\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{4})\\
y=3 \sin(t+\frac{\pi}{4})\\
z= \frac{3\sqrt3}{2}\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{4})
\end{cases} \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ z=\sqrt{3} \  y$$

which is translated into set langage by:

"The curve is **included** into the plane with equation  $z=\sqrt{3} \  x.$"

Moreover, this curve is described by a periodical parametrization (see figure below).

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in your answer

Comment: But why was it possible to eliminate the y coordinate?

Comment: I think he means $z=\sqrt{3} x$

Comment: @harlem I do not eliminate the information about $y$, I ignore it. We need an $\implies$ not an $\iff$...

Comment: @harlem I have transformed my answer, thinking to the general case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the plane normal direction $\bf n$ and a point on the plane $\bf r$ then the point $\bf p$ lies on the plane if

$$ {\bf n} \cdot ( {\bf p}-{\bf r} ) =0$$